# MySQL- Average of 15 minutes intervals

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
╔════════════╦══════════╦═══════╦══════╗
║    DATE    ║   TIME   ║ Price ║ Avg  ║
╠════════════╬══════════╬═══════╬══════╣
║ 01/01/2000 ║ 00:00:00 ║   1   ║      ║
║ 01/01/2000 ║ 00:05:00 ║   2   ║      ║
║ 01/01/2000 ║ 00:10:00 ║   3   ║      ║
║ 01/01/2000 ║ 00:15:00 ║   4   ║      ║
║ 01/01/2000 ║ 00:20:00 ║   5   ║      ║
║ 01/01/2000 ║ 00:25:00 ║   6   ║      ║
║ 01/01/2000 ║ 00:30:00 ║   7   ║      ║
║ 01/01/2000 ║ 00:35:00 ║   8   ║      ║
║ 01/01/2000 ║ 00:40:00 ║   9   ║      ║
║ 01/01/2000 ║ 00:45:00 ║   10  ║      ║
║ 01/01/2000 ║ 00:50:00 ║   11  ║      ║
║ 01/01/2000 ║ 00:55:00 ║   12  ║      ║
║ 01/01/2000 ║ 01:00:00 ║   13  ║      ║
╚════════════╩══════════╩═══════╩══════╝
```

And I want to fill the column Avg with a moving average of price of the last 15 minutes (not including the last average), so that the outcome is:

```
╔════╦════════════╦══════════╦═══════╦══════╗
║ ID ║    DATE    ║   TIME   ║ Price ║ Avg  ║
╠════╬════════════╬══════════╬═══════╬══════╣
║ 1  ║ 01/01/2000 ║ 00:00:00 ║   10  ║  10  ║
║ 2  ║ 01/01/2000 ║ 00:05:00 ║   2   ║      ║
║ 3  ║ 01/01/2000 ║ 00:10:00 ║   6   ║      ║
║ 4  ║ 01/01/2000 ║ 00:15:00 ║   4   ║  4   ║ <-- Average of 2,6,4
║ 5  ║ 01/01/2000 ║ 00:20:00 ║   7   ║      ║
║ 6  ║ 01/01/2000 ║ 00:25:00 ║   6   ║      ║
║ 7  ║ 01/01/2000 ║ 00:30:00 ║   5   ║  6   ║ <-- Average of 7,6,5
║ 8  ║ 01/01/2000 ║ 00:35:00 ║   2   ║      ║
║ 9  ║ 01/01/2000 ║ 00:40:00 ║   2   ║      ║
║ 10 ║ 01/01/2000 ║ 00:45:00 ║   2   ║  2   ║ <-- Average of 2,2,2
║ 11 ║ 01/01/2000 ║ 00:50:00 ║   10  ║      ║
║ 12 ║ 01/01/2000 ║ 00:55:00 ║   12  ║      ║
║ 13 ║ 01/01/2000 ║ 01:00:00 ║   2   ║  8   ║ <-- Average of 10,12,2
╚════╩════════════╩══════════╩═══════╩══════╝
```

NOTE: While there is ALWAYS an entry every 5 minutes, there could be additional entries in between(i.e.: There could be a price at 00:32:00).

What I have right now is the following:

```
UPDATE table AS t 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT AVG(Price) as average,
    floor((unix_timestamp(CONCAT(date, ' ', time)))/900 ) as timekey
FROM table
GROUP BY timekey ) t1 
ON t.ID = t1.ID
SET 15_MIN_AVERAGE = t1.average
```

But this seems to group the entries that are on the 15 minutes and the next ones, instead of the previous ones like I want.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the type of your `TIME` column?  Are you storing date/time data as varchar?

Comment: No, it is type TIME

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do what you want with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select avg(t2.price)
        from table t2
        where t2.time <= t.time and t2.time >= date_sub(t.time, interval 15 minute)
       ) as avgprice
from table t;
```

You can then do tbe update that you want, using this in a `join`:

```
update table t join
       (select t.*,
               (select avg(t2.price)
                from table t2
                where t2.time <= t.time and t2.time >= date_sub(t.time, interval 15 minute)
               ) as avgprice
        from table t
       ) tt
       on t.id = tt.id
    set t.15_MIN_AVERAGE = ttavgprice
    where minute(t.time) in (0, 15, 30, 45);
```

Comment: That works great, thanks!

Although I do have a few million records in this table, so updating the whole table takes around an hour of processing. Is there any optimization that could be done?

How about adding indexes on time?

Comment: @VincentLavoie . . . An index on `(time, price)` might help performance.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Hi, I posted a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76609413/grafana-query-mysql-database-and-compute-30-minute-average