# Compute 30 minute moving average

Tags: mysql

With the motivation from the answer given in the below link, I constructed the following query:
ref: https://ubiq.co/database-blog/calculate-moving-average-mysql/

Timestamp in the MySql database is not configured to the UTC. Hence, in the below, query, I am converting timestamp first to the UTC and calling it as time_stamp. Then, I am performing the moving average by considering the samples between the current time and 30 minutes before.  :

```
SELECT
       convert_tz(a.timestamp,'US/Central','UTC') as time_stamp,
       a.current_value,
       a.thisMonthPeakValue, a.lastMonthPeakValue, 
       Round( ( SELECT SUM(b.current_value) / COUNT(b.current_value)
                FROM my_db.hourly_values AS b
                WHERE time_stamp BETWEEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AND SUBTIME(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),"00:30:00")
              ), 2 ) AS 30minAvg
     FROM my_df.hourly_values AS a
ORDER BY time_stamp DESC 
LIMIT 10000;
```

Presently I am not getting any error but it is not displaying results and remains forever in execution mode.

Comment: `WHERE  time_stamp BETWEEN` -- Is that `a.time_stamp`?  or `b.time_stamp`?  I think it is `b.` and you probably wanted `a.`?

Comment: If this will be a recurring query, let's talk about [_Summary Tables_](https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables)

Comment: `SUM(b.current_value) / COUNT(b.current_value)` might be simply `AVG(b.current_value)`?

Comment: @RickJames @RickJames I tried this one. No errors but also no output. Just continuous execution `SELECT
       convert_tz(a.timestamp,'US/Central','UTC') as time_stamp_a,
       a.current_value,
       a.thisMonthPeakValue, a.lastMonthPeakValue, 
       (select 
       avg(b.current_value)
       FROM evchargecontrol.algorithm_values AS b 
       where time_stamp_a <= current_time() and time_stamp_a >= date_sub(time_stamp_a, interval 15 minute)
       ) as minAvg

     FROM my_df.hourly_values AS a
ORDER BY time_stamp DESC 
LIMIT 10000;`

Comment: `time_stamp_a >= date_sub(time_stamp_a, interval 15 minute)` is always TRUE.

Comment: @RickJames Good catch. Any other approach?

Comment: Please update the Question and desk check for any further typos.